# How do I show that the probability of the union of events is not larger than the sum of the individual probabilities using induction?

Tags: probability

In numeric analysis class, we are supposed to show that
$P(\bigcup_{n \in N} A_n) \le \sum_{n \in N} P(A_n)$.

please can someone help me out?

Comment: what are your thoughts? $N$ is natural numbers? Then induction is not really a proof option, as the proof is not about indivual $n$.

Comment: Or is $N$ a fixed finite number?

Comment: And learn mathjax for formatting, please.

Comment: What if the n stands for individual n?

Comment: I am kinda new here,what is mathjax?

Comment: What is the *exact* statement?

Comment: Your question has the answer inside of it: "using induction". Do you know the induction principle?

Comment: Not quite. I am not a major in statistics just borrowing a course from there

Comment: [Mathjax intro](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank your for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Large Hint:**

For $N=1$ the statement is trvially true since $\cup_{n=1}^NA_n=A_1$. Let it be true for some natural number $m$. Then, let $A_1,\dots,A_{m+1}$ be $m+1$ events and also let $B:=\bigcup_{n=1}^mA_n$ and $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{m+1}A_n$, so we observe that:
$$A=B\cup A_{m+1}.$$
So, we have:
$$\begin{align}
P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{m+1}A_n\right)&=P(A)=P(B\cup A_{m+1})=P(B)+P(A_{m+1})-P(B\cap A_{m+1})\\
&\leq P(B)+P(A_{m+1})\leq\sum_{n=1}^mP(A_n)+P(A_{m+1})=\sum_{n=1}^{m+1}P(A_n)
\end{align}$$
which is the wanted inequality.

So, for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^NP(A_n).$$

Now, note that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^NP(A_n)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)$$
so we also ahve:
$$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n).$$
Now, we would like to take limits as $N\to\infty$ and get the wanted inequality, but for this to be possible we would like to know that it is true that:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n\right)=P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right).$$

Can you prove the latter taking into consideration that for every $n<m$ we have:
$$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nP(A_k)\right)\leq P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^mP(A_k)\right)?$$

**Edit/Further Info:**
As for the last result, note that the sequence $B_n:=A_n\setminus\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k$ and $B_1=A_1$ is a sequence of disjoint sets (events) such that:
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^NB_n\ \forall N\in\mathbb{N}$$
and
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$$
but, since $B_n$ are disjoint, we have that:
$$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(B_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^NP(B_n)$$
On the other hand:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^NP(B_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n\right)$$
and the proof is complete.

Comment: I cant prove it perfectly canu please help me?

Comment: I was off, I've added some details now.